# Cant install or run any app offline in tiny core linux? mounting /dev/loop123 on /tmp/tcloop/gtk1 failed Invalid Argument

Tags: linux, installation, operating-systems

I tried everything. downloaded dependencies and dep files for elmerfm and the program itself, actually downloaded all files like md5.txt, list, info... Put them to sda1/tce/optional/ . Also my tce is set to that location in app manager (whatever its called). Tried puting it onboot. When entered mount in terminal it shows many loopxx mounted up until loop123 where xx is number from 0 to 122. I have 3 GB RAM. Formated primary bootable partition using ext4 and tried installing os on it, says no operating system installed. However using CD works, and it accesses it for tce dir. actually same message about mounting loop123 invalid argument shows at startup on boot screen. Even on fresh CD and reformated HD.